# Load script with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a very strange problem. This function load a script on my IIS local web server.

```
function loadJs(scriptName) {
    var name = scriptName.toString();
    var myUrl = 'http://192.168.1.149/7.0.9.5/m/js/';
    myUrl += name;
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function () {  }
    });
}
```

When I check in debugger, I see that the url is correct.

[image]

But in fact, the ajax call doesn't use my url:
[image]

While it should be this:

[image]

We can see that the request url is not the same. (The 403 code is normal because IIS block the access to the folder list).

On the other hand, if I directly put the url into the 'url' parameter, the load works.

```
function loadJs(scriptName) {
    var name = scriptName.toString();
    var myUrl = 'http://192.168.1.149/7.0.9.5/m/js/';
    myUrl += name;
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.149/7.0.9.5/m/js/loadAccount.js',
        dataType: "script",
        success: function () {  }
    });
}
```

[image]

If someone can propose an answer to this very strange problem. I'll be glad.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What do you mean the script doesn't use the url?

Because there are 2 network entires there, one with 200 and one with 403. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: As you can see, the url request don't have the 'scriptName' var I added to the end of my 'myUrl'.

Comment: I can't really see, I can only guess. I assume that the first call with status `200` is what happens when you run the last piece of code and the second call with status `403` is what you get when you run the first piece of code? It is really confusing this way.

Comment: Could you show us how you call that loadJs function?

Comment: After trying out a few things your code keeps working for me. Is it possible to create an example in jsbin/jsfiddle that also doesn't work? What browser are you using, what version of jQuery, maybe try updating jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
myUrl = myUrl + name;
```

Comment: Same problem by changing this line.

Comment: Check in your debugger for the value of myUrl, but this time check on line no.7 (i.e. url : myUrl). whether or not it is showing correct/incorrect url

Comment: I checked I have the same url.

Comment: `myUrl += value` does the same thing

Comment: try `myUrl = myUrl.concat(name)` Also check .toString() function, is it returning the exact string you neeed?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this late answer...
I found the problem, in fact I had severals scripts loaded, the first worked but the second 'scriptname' was in real empty. This justify the 403 forbidden message error (reject consultation of file in IIS).